# How to know which file or directory is the last one when listing recursively?

Tags: c#, recursion, io, .net-standard

#### Introduction

I'm writing a library which comes with `DirectoryTreeDrawer` class. Its main purpose is to draw a tree structure (to underlying [`TextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2)) based on provided directory path or [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) instance.

#### Demo

Here is a sample .NET Core console application utilizing the `DirectoryTreeDrawer` class:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var drawer = new DirectoryTreeDrawer(System.Console.Out))
        {
            var workingDirectoryPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            drawer.DrawTree(workingDirectoryPath);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Sample output

Running the above will produce output similar to these few lines below (truncated for brevity):

```
ConsoleDemo\
├────ConsoleDemo.csproj.nuget.cache
├────ConsoleDemo.csproj.nuget.g.props
├────ConsoleDemo.csproj.nuget.g.targets
├────project.assets.json
├──ConsoleDemo.csproj
├──Program.cs
```

#### How it works

`DrawTree()` calls `PrintDirectoryContent()` where the recursion magic begins. Starting from the provided path, the program iterates recursively through subdirectories and prints names of files and directories in a manner reflecting the relative depth from the original directory.

```
public void DrawTree(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var searchPattern = "*";
    var searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;

    PrintDirectoryName(directoryInfo, depth: 0);
    PrintDirectoryContent(directoryInfo, searchPattern, searchOption, depth: 0);
}

private void PrintDirectoryContent(DirectoryInfo currentDirectory, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, int depth)
{
    var directories = currentDirectory.GetDirectories(searchPattern, searchOption);
    var directoriesCount = directories.GetLength(0);
    for (var directoryIndex = 0; directoryIndex < directoriesCount; directoryIndex++)
    {
        var directoryInfo = directories[directoryIndex];
        PrintDirectoryName(directoryInfo, depth + 1);
        PrintDirectoryContent(directoryInfo, searchPattern, searchOption, depth + 1);
    }

    var files = currentDirectory.GetFiles(searchPattern, searchOption);
    var filesCount = files.GetLength(0);
    for (var fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < filesCount; fileIndex++)
    {
        var fileInfo = files[fileIndex];
        PrintFileName(fileInfo, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

#### Helper methods

The file (or directory) prefix consists of a single `├` sign followed by repetitions of `─` sign respectively to the current depth.

```
private void PrintDirectoryName(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, int depth)
{
    _textWriter.WriteLine($"{CreateDepthPrefix(depth)}{directoryInfo.Name}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}");
}

private void PrintFileName(FileInfo fileInfo, int depth)
{
    _textWriter.WriteLine($"{CreateDepthPrefix(depth)}{fileInfo.Name}");
}

private string CreateDepthPrefix(int depth)
{
    return $"{'├'}{new string('─', 2 * depth)}";
}
```

## Question

I would like to mark the last entry (file or directory) with different prefix than the usual one. Instead of starting the prefix with `├` sign, I would like to start it with `└` sign. So the last line of output instead of:

```
├──Program.cs
```

...would look like this:

```
└──Program.cs
```

For me, the problem comes to the question of how to know which file or directory is the last one to print. If I could know it, I could simply run a check while printing the prefix.

Is there a better solution then saving all entries (files and directories names and depth) to a collection, and then performing a check against "being-the-last-entry" condition? Or maybe it is the only one?

#### Code repository

The library is open source, available on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/fluorite/tree-drawers). Here you can also find the original [`DirectoryTreeDrawer`](https://gitlab.com/fluorite/tree-drawers/blob/master/src/TreeDrawers/DirectoryTreeDrawer.cs) class. Take notice that I edited it quite heavily, for code brevity purposes.

#### Final notice

I would like to make it clear, that I'm not asking for a code review just as it might seem to someone. I'm facing a problem and I'm asking for solution.

Comment: You have the count of directories and files, so you know which is the last one, so you could modify your methods to take a `lastItem` parameter, which you could use in `CreateDepthPrefix` to determine which character to begin the prefix with.

Comment: Also, you can use the `Length` property instead of the `GetLength()` method

Comment: The famous Jon Skeet wrote a `SmartEnumerable` class that includes properties `IsFirst` and `IsLast` that would help you do what you want.  See https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/index.html

Comment: _"Here you can also find the original DirectoryTreeDrawer class"_ -- your question should include a [mcve], not snippets from a git repo. Please edit it so that you have a correct, complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My short answer is what I wrote in the comments, and which Peter has already provided an answer for, but here's an alternative format that may be considered more readable, which provides indenting for each directory and file, so that it's easier to see which parent it belongs to. See the last image for sample output.

This is done by keeping track of the last file or folder in a parent and passing that to the `PrintItem` method (which is the answer I proposed in the comments to your question). Another change is that the prefix is passed along from parent to child, so that we can include the connector for nested items. To keep track of items that are "nested" (meaning that the item's parent has siblings that are displayed after the current item), we pass an `IsNested` parameter to the `PrintDirectory` method, so that the prefix can be updated accordingly.

I also modified it to be a `static` class which passes the `TextWriter` around to the different methods. Not sure if this is really any better, but aside from the `TextWriter`, everything else seemed like it should be static.

```
public static class DirectoryTreeDrawer
{
    public static void DrawTree(string directoryPath, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        DrawTree(new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath), textWriter);
    }

    public static void DrawTree(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        PrintDirectory(directoryInfo, textWriter);
    }

    private static void PrintDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory, TextWriter textWriter, 
        string prefix = "  ", string searchPattern = "*", SearchOption searchOption = 
        SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, bool isLast = true, bool isNested = false)
    {
        PrintItem(directory.Name, prefix, isLast, textWriter, true);

        var subDirs = directory.GetDirectories(searchPattern, searchOption);
        var files = directory.GetFiles(searchPattern, searchOption);

        // If this is a "nested" directory, add the parent's connector to the prefix
        prefix += isNested ? "│ " : "  ";

        for (var directoryIndex = 0; directoryIndex < subDirs.Length; directoryIndex++)
        {
            var isLastChild = directoryIndex == subDirs.Length - 1 && files.Length == 0;

            // If the parent has files or other directories, mark this as "nested"
            var isNestedDir = files.Length > 0 || !isLastChild;

            PrintDirectory(subDirs[directoryIndex], textWriter, prefix, searchPattern, 
                searchOption, isLastChild, isNestedDir);
        }            

        for (var fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < files.Length; fileIndex++)
        {
            var isLastFile = fileIndex == files.Length - 1;

            PrintItem(files[fileIndex].Name, prefix, isLastFile, textWriter);
        }
    }

    private static void PrintItem(string name, string prefix, bool isLastItem, 
        TextWriter textWriter, bool isDirectory = false)
    {
        var itemConnector = isLastItem ? "└─" : "├─";
        var suffix = isDirectory ? Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() : "";

        textWriter?.WriteLine($"{prefix}{itemConnector}{name}{suffix}");
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private static void Main()
{
    DirectoryTreeDrawer.DrawTree(Environment.CurrentDirectory, Console.Out);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: Sample Output]

And, judging from the output, it's clear that I've been reusing this same project for many years and it has a bunch of extraneous files in the `Debug` folder... :)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. With code it is much easier to understand what you were talking about in comments. And about the `static` matter... I'm not sure myself which way I should go, but that is a different story.

Comment: Yeah, it was hard to describe, glad it made sense in code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, I would list them all then change cursor position and then change the printed character:

```
public void DrawTree(string directoryPath)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(directoryPath))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "Provided directory path is null, emtpy " +
                    "or consists of only whitespace characters.",
                    nameof(directoryPath));
            }

            DrawTree(new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath));
            //remember current position because we need to return position to it
            int currentCursorPositionTop = Console.CursorTop;
            //set position to the last row
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop-1);
            //change the first charachter
            Console.Write("└");
            //return cursor position to the previous one so our "Press any key to continue" can apear below our list.
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentCursorPositionTop);
        }
```

I hope this helps.
and this is how it looks like when change is applied:
[image]

**Update:**
In order to maintain a higher level of abstractions, I suggest writing data into 
List and then just change the prefix of the last one:

```
class ContentItem {
    public string Prefix {get;set; }
    public int Depth {get;set; }
    public string Name {get;set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return $"{Prefix}{(new String("-", Depth))} {Name}";
    }
}
```

So instead changing console cursor position you can change list item prefix:

```
 var items[items.Count()-1].Prefix = "└";
```

and then you loop thru the items and pass them to your TextWriter, StreamWriter or whatever.

Comment: Your solution uses methods provided by `Console` class. Thus, it won't work for `TextWriter` or `StreamWriter`. Using `Console` imposes specific usage scenario and I would like to maintain a higher level of abstraction, which I believe using `TextWriter` provides.

Comment: You could just use `Console.Out` for the `TextWriter` in the code if you want to write to the console...

Answer (score -1):

> the problem comes to the question of how to know which file or directory is the last one to print. If I could know it, I could simply run a check while printing the prefix.

Given the code you posted, it is trivial to know if you are at the last entry, because your recursive method has a `depth` parameter, and your loop for each item is indexed. This means you only need to look at your `int` values, e.g.:

```
private void PrintDirectoryContent(DirectoryInfo currentDirectory, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, int depth)
{
    var directories = currentDirectory.GetDirectories(searchPattern, searchOption);
    var directoriesCount = directories.GetLength(0);
    for (var directoryIndex = 0; directoryIndex < directoriesCount; directoryIndex++)
    {
        var directoryInfo = directories[directoryIndex];
        PrintDirectoryName(directoryInfo, depth + 1);
        PrintDirectoryContent(directoryInfo, searchPattern, searchOption, depth + 1);
    }

    var files = currentDirectory.GetFiles(searchPattern, searchOption);
    var filesCount = files.GetLength(0);
    for (var fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < filesCount; fileIndex++)
    {
        var fileInfo = files[fileIndex];
        PrintFileName(fileInfo, depth + 1, depth == 0 && fileIndex == filesCount - 1);
    }
}

private void PrintDirectoryName(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, int depth)
{
    _textWriter.WriteLine($"{CreateDepthPrefix('├', depth)}{directoryInfo.Name}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}");
}

private void PrintFileName(FileInfo fileInfo, int depth, bool isLast)
{
    _textWriter.WriteLine($"{CreateDepthPrefix(isLast ? '└' : '├', depth)}{fileInfo.Name}");
}

private string CreateDepthPrefix(char initialChar, int depth)
{
    return $"{initialChar}{new string('─', 2 * depth)}";
}
```

I.e. the expression `depth == 0 && fileIndex == filesCount - 1` serves as the exact value for the `isLast` parameter that I added to the `PrintFileName()` method.

Note that lacking a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I had to make some adjustments to the code you posted to get it to compile and run. The code you posted also does not produce the output your question says it does; specifically, the top-level directory name winds up with the `'├'` character as well. I guess in your actual code, you special-case that line.

I didn't spend any time trying to get the output to match up exactly with what you said it was, preferring instead to just focus on the question at hand. I assume that you can adapt the code above, which contains the answer to that question, to whatever code you actually have.